# Disable creation of default content during installation

Tags: installation

How can I disable or at least modify the default content inserted on a fresh wordpress install? For example to change the category from Uncategorised to News.

Answer (score 1):

The default Category of 'Uncategorized' it is hard-coded in several places.  However, check out upgrade.php line # 109.

If you would like to change the first posts check out the schema.php file located wp-admin/includes/schema.php line # 712
From there you can edit the first post.

Answer (score 0):

Its prob not worth the trouble pre-install unless you have a specific concern, it will take much less time to do the following,

Log in and change the name "uncategorised' to something of your liking.
The default content contains 1 post and 1 comment, go ahead and trash them.
Done.

Comment: Yes I know I can do that, just wondering whether there is something I can modify, what if I wanted to always create a number of pages automatically?